# how to choose a specific direcrory entry within directory iterator

Tags: c++

My question is very specific, sorry for that.

From this code:

```
int i = 0;
for(auto& p: recursive_directory_iterator("stru1")) {
    ++i;
    cout << "Index no." << i <<  p.path() << '\n';
```

in this the loop will iterates over every entity in the directory and output the path with their index number.

My question is if there is anyway where, after the loop is done, I can choose a specific index and display the content of the index's directory?

Comment: Please don't apologize for asking a specific question. That's exactly what you should do.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to be certain you get the same entry (if there are concurrent modifications to that directory) would be to build a vector during iteration:

```
std::size_t i = 0;
std::vector<std::filesystem::directory_entry> entries;
for(auto& p: std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("stru1")) {
    ++i;
    std::cout << "Index no." << i <<  p.path() << '\n';
    entries.push_back(p);
}

if (std::cin >> i && i >= 1 && i <= entries.size()) {
    auto const & entry = entries[i - 1];
    // use entry
}
```

Comment: so after getting the entry is there a way to display its file content?

Comment: @user11370788 Sure. Open it and pipe the content to cout.

Comment: I am sorry but can you get more specific? what exactly should I use?

Comment: @user11370788 Open the file with [`std::fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream), read input, write to `std::cout`, repeat until you can't read anymore.